# Prove that for every positive integer $d$ that divides $2n,$ $D_{2n}$ has a subgroup of order $d$.

Tags: group-theory

Consider $D_{2n}$, the dihedral group of order ${2n}$. Prove that for every positive integer $d$ that divides $2n,$ $D_{2n}$ has a subgroup of order $d$.

My idea:

First consider if $d$ divides $n$. In this case we can just consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$, where $a$ is a rotation through $2\pi/n.$

Since $d$ divides $n$ we have $n=dk$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Consider $a^k.$ $$(a^k)^d=a^{dk}=a^n=e$$

Now suppose $a^k$ has order less than $d$. This implies that $a$ has order less than $n$ and so we have a contradiction. Thus we have a cyclic subgroup of order $d$.

Now consider if $d$ does not divide $n$.

This is where I'm stuck, what should I do for this part?

Comment: It's not true; there can be lots of divisors of $2n$ that aren't divisors of $n$ (look at $n=105$ for example).

Comment: Yeah thats not true, my bad

Comment: Here's a hint: note that 3 divides 15. Can you find an injective homomorphism from $D_6$ into $D_{30}$? (Perhaps it should be similar to an embedding of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z$....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $d$ does not divide $n$. Then $\frac{d}{2}$ divides $n$ (and $d$ is even). So, if we write $D_{2n}=<
\sigma, \rho>$ where $\sigma$ is the reflection through the $x$-axis and $\rho$ is rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians. By the same reasoning as in your question we have a subgroup of $<\rho>$ of order $\frac{d}{2}$. This subgroup is generated by $\rho^{\frac{2n}{d}}$. Now we just 'add' $\sigma$ to this subgroup, that is, we look at the set $$\{\rho^{\frac{2n}{d}i}, \rho^{\frac{2n}{d}i}\sigma | i \in \{1, .., \frac{d}{2}\}\}.$$
This set has $d$ elements, and one easily checks, with the relation $\sigma \rho^k \sigma = \rho^{-k}$, that this is a subgroup of $D_{2n}$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your statement 'By the same reasoning...'. Could you explain why we get a subgroup of order $\frac{d}{2}$ please?

Comment: Yes.  $<\rho>$ is cyclic of order n, so for any divisor $l$ of $n$ we have a subgroup of that order, this is a theorem. You gave the proof yourself in your question, when you took the generators of $a^k$!